# ERROR: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_batch

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe that take a long time to execute (2 hours) and I am getting this error

ERROR: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_batch

As you see, it is on a windows machine.

Do I need to increase a time-out timer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [shell-out code](https://github.com/opscode/mixlib-shellout/blob/master/lib/mixlib/shellout/windows.rb), you can see (look for "WAIT_TIMEOUT"), that when the shell command receives times out, chef throws explicit CommandTimeout Exception. So there must be some other error you receive.